# Take array of indices, find matching indices in another array and replace values

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have two arrays, one array that contains all indices of two arrays that meet a certain condition I had made previous to this. The other array is an array of booleans. I want to take the array of indices and find the same place in the array of booleans and replace those values.

So for example what I am looking to do is:

```
myIdxs = [0, 3, 5]
myBools = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

and change myBools to:

```
myBools = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I've tried:

```
myBools = [myBools[i] for i in myIdx == 0]
```

But this does not give me the desired output.

Comment: We index starting from `0` and so shouldn't it be `myBools = [0,1,1,0,1,1]` assuming we are switching every `0` to a `1` and vice versa? How do you get  `myBools = [1,0,0,1,0,0]`?

Comment: My apologies, I was not clear and did not keep things straight. I have edited the question with the correct index from 0

Comment: Unclear again, Shouldn't the output according to your logic be `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`?

Comment: I want to change the values of myBools to 0 at the indices given by myIndxs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poorly worded question, but here are two answers, both are extremely simple and straightforward, and don't required complex list comprehension.

**If you want to change the bit to the opposite value**

```
    myIdxs = [0, 3, 5]
    myBools = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

    for i in myIdxs:
        myBools[i] ^= 1  # Bitwise operator flips the bit

    print(myBools)
```

**If you want to change the bit to zero.**

```
    myIdxs = [0, 3, 5]
    myBools = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

    for i in myIdxs:
        myBools[i] = 0  # Sets bit to zero

    print(myBools)
```

**Output**

The output is actually the same for both, given the input, but don't let that fool you they do two very different things.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I will try to be more clear in the future. I was trying to convey the latter, and your solution worked. Thanks for your insight and help

Answer (score 3):

I hope this works (not sure what you need):

```
myIdxs = [0, 3, 5]
myBools = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

myBools = [myBools[i] if i in myIdxs else 0
        for i in xrange(len(myBools))]

>>> print myBools
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using list comprehension with if-else statement.

```
[myBools[i] if i in myIdxs else 0 for i in range(len(myBools))]
```

**Output**

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This answer reiterates what has already been mentioned in another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37928682/4099593).

Comment: @BhargavRao I didn't see while posting mine. But Thanks for pointing it out.